# OS X today widget not updating its snapshot

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, today-extension

I'm developing an OS X today widget similar to the builtin Weather widget. It runs fine in Xcode's widget simulator. However, after I export it as an Mac app, the today widget in notification center always show the last snapshot that was created while running in widget simulator previously. The correct behavior should be that, whenever the notification center slides out, the today widget fetches the user's current location and display the local time and weather.

Here is what I have in the `widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler`:

```
  func widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler(completionHandler: ((NCUpdateResult) -> Void)!) {
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    completionHandler(.NewData)
  }
```

Comment: Did you have any luck figuring this out? I'm running into a similar problem with one of my Mac apps.

Comment: After you launch your Mac app, try force restarting Notification Center in Activity Monitor.  This should reload each of the widgets, and will hopefully load the latest version of your code.

Comment: @ChristopherRung Cheers, I was having the same symptoms as the OP, and this worked for me

Comment: Glad to hear it, @Vince!